# How to insert into `MutableHashTable` on the fly in computation graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, insert, hashtable

#### Model Requirements

I'm building a simple tensorflow model that needs to store/build a ID==>INDEX map on the fly so it can be trained online on a dataset thats being built in realtime, i.e. the dataset doesn't exist to prebuild the map (otherwise I would).

Of course, I can build the map outside of the tensorflow computation graph (and transforming every ID to INDEX before feeding model inputs) but we would really like the model to be self contained at save time to  simplify future prediction/computation tasks.

#### Approach

I'm trying to use tensorflow's `MutableHashTable` for this but keep running into "catchya's" from tensorflow. I've confirmed that I can insert new key/value items into the hash table via

```
# defined in computation graph
id_to_idx = tf.contrib.lookup.MutableHashTable(tf.int32, tf.int32, MISSING_KEY_VALUE)

# .. with an open tf.Session

keys = [123, 234, 456, 567]
vals = [0,1,2,3]
sess.run(id_to_idx.insert(keys, vals))

sess.run(id_to_idx.lookup(keys))
# Returns [0,1,2,3]
```

What I'd like todo is make this an operation on the graph so new keys are identified, assigned incremental values, then inserted into the hash table to use in the rest of the model.

I'd like to have something like this,

```
# defined in computation graph
id_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,))
update_hashtable = id_to_idx.insert(new_keys, new_values)
indices = id_to_idx.lookup(id_inputs)

# .. with open tf.Session()

batch_of_somenew_and_someold_ids = [13,563,673,23]
sess.run([update_hashtable, indices], feed_dict={id_inputs: batch_of_somenew_and_someold_ids)
# Updates hash table values then returns them with next op
```

#### Minimal Example

```
import tensorflow as tf

MISSING_KEY_VALUE = -1

id_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,))
id_to_idx = tf.contrib.lookup.MutableHashTable(tf.int32, tf.int32, MISSING_KEY_VALUE)
_next_idx = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32)

#
# Update Hash Table
#
_indices = id_to_idx.lookup(id_inputs) # initial lookup from hash
_not_seen_loc = tf.not_equal(_indices, MISSING_KEY_VALUE) # location in batch of IDs that haven't been seen
_ids_not_seen_yet = tf.where(_not_seen_loc, id_inputs, id_inputs) # list of the IDs that haven't been seen
_end_idx = _next_idx + tf.size(_not_seen_loc) 
_new_indices = tf.range(_next_idx, _end_idx) # new hash tables values for these keys

# Operation to update the idx iterator for next batch of inputs
update_iter = _next_idx.assign(_end_idx)

# *should* be an operation that makes the insert
update_hashtable = id_to_idx.insert(_ids_not_seen_yet, _new_indices)

# Operation to get mapped IDs for batch
indices = id_to_idx.lookup(id_inputs)

# .. Graph continues and does ML stuff
```

Running this example,

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  # some mock input data pulled off a dataset obj
  batch_ids = [34, 532, 5, 234, 6]

  _, iter_val, batch_indices = sess.run([update_hashtable, update_iter indices], feed_dict={id_inputs: batch_ids})
```

yields the error

`Fetch argument <function update_hashtable at 0x1384401e0> has invalid type <class 'function'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a function into a Tensor or Operation.)`

which seems weird because `id_to_idx.insert(keys,vals)` should return an operation (as described in the docs and the test example).

I've confirmed the idx iterator is incrementing properly by printing the result after each batch of 16,

```
[16,32,48,64,80,96,112,128,144,160,176]
```

#### Questions

1. Does `MutableHashTable` not work inside the computation graph? The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/MutableHashTable#insert) says that inputs can be tensors.
2. Printing the type of `update_hashtable`, Why isn't this returning an operation (like the in the lookup case)?

```
print(type(update_hashtable))
print(type(indices))

# <class 'function'>
# <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

3. Am I approaching this problem incorrectly?  Is there a known/better solution to this problem?